# Amazon S3 for images/videos or server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I notice that a lot of people prefer upload the images and videos in storage services like AWS S3. Those images are such a slider, logo, product's images, random images, etc.

What is the big difference to upload those images in the server or in a services like S3?

Prices? Bandwidth? Access? It is more fast? Scalability?

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 1):

Please read it,

https://www.linkeit.com/blog/what-is-amazon-s3-and-its-benefits

in case if you will use your server for static files you will need maintain

1. Scalability
2. Security
3. Backups ( You need do it reliable and durable )
   And many other